# URL to image transformation

Tags: javascript

I use this function for transforming URLs to images on output.

```
function InsertLink(T){
 var Out = '';
 var T1=T;
 var LinkR = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?([^?#]*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))/;
 var Pos=0;
 for(var N=0;(N=T1.search(LinkR))!==-1;){
    var S1 = T1.match(LinkR)[0];
    var S1L = S1.length;
    Out += T1.substr(0,N)+"<a href='"+S1+"' target='_blank'><img class='sml' src='"+S1+"' /></a><br />";
    T1 = T1.substr(N+S1L);
    Pos=N+S1L;
 };
 Out+=T1;
 return Out;
}
```

But it working only for one URL in post body. If text contains more than one URL, all URLs attached to one image ("broken" image).

What's wrong?

Comment: I see that you aren't even using `Pos`.
Try this: replace `var S1 = T1.match(LinkR)[0];` with `var S1 = T1.match(LinkR)[Pos];` or this `var S1 = N[0];`

Comment: Thanks, but using Pos makes no effect.

Comment: This whole thing can be done in one line of code using the replace function

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware, I'm using a different RegEx which selects any url, not just images, so I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/C3zF6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the jsFiddle for how to do it, the code you need is in the `replaceWithImgLinks` function

http://jsfiddle.net/C3zF6/1/

I had trouble getting your regex to work so I used the one from here: [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)