# url source to Image javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986575/url-to-image-transformation) and i want to use its answer, however as overwrites everything i put in, if I for example add a red div it vanish. How can i make this javascript work well with my other html...

```
var newHTML = replaceWithImgLinks($(document.body).text());
$(document.body).html(newHTML);
function replaceWithImgLinks(txt) {
var linkRegex = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))/gi;
var replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img class="sml" src="$1" /></a><br />'
return txt.replace(linkRegex, replacement);
}
```

(Im stupid and my javascript knowledge is not the best) if you could explain why it doesn't work aswell i would be very satisfied.:)

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eju2ea2/) aswell so you can see my problem:

So what I am trying to do is so all the imgs srcs in my div is changed to images "instead of the whole body i think"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the parameters of the URL, you can use `\S*` at the end of the regex.

```
/([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))\S*/gi
```

Also, I've changed the classes that you call & replace within JQuery:

```js
function replaceWithImgLinks(txt) {
    var linkRegex = /([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))\S*/gi;
    return txt.replace(linkRegex, '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img class="sml" src="$1" /></a><br />');
}

var newHTML = replaceWithImgLinks($('.chatMessages').html());
$('.chatMessages').html(newHTML);
```

```css
.chatMessages{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
.sml{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "chatMessages">
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1
</div>
```

Comment: oh thanks alot, i tried to set document.(.chatMessages) before but it didn't work but i guess you only need to set .chatMessages instead of document body, and thanks aswell for helping me with my "next" problem with the parameters!

Comment: is there another way to remove parameters than \S* because it messes up my php of some reason?